# How to fix unmet dependencies with libgtk-3-dev on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, dependencies, gtk

I'm trying to install wxWidgets, and on the [installation guide](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/plat_gtk_install.html) they mention on Ubuntu I'd need the libgtk-3-dev package.

However, when I try to install it with

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (= 3.24.18-1ubuntu1) but 3.24.20-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libepoxy-dev (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libfontconfig1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.41) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.24.18-1ubuntu1) but 3.24.20-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

And the command exits with the following error 100: `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

What are the steps I need to take to correct this?

Comment: None of the answers in the two linked question help at all. This should have not been closed. Closing legit questions like this diminishes the value of the site.

Comment: I have the same issue, unable to do `sudo apt install libatk-bridge2.0-dev`, the error says something about the dependencies:
```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatk-bridge2.0-dev : Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0 (= 2.34.1-3) but 2.34.2-0ubuntu2~20.04.1 is to be installed
```

Comment: I'd hate to reopen a question this old?  Perhaps re-ask?  But about half the time the reason for this is you are trying to install backdated items and proceeding will damage your system.  The other half of the time, it's a third party repo with odd dependencies or overlaps with ubuntu packages.

Comment: Sometimes `apt policy ...` is helpful.